# Get Specific data from database in Android FCM

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps

Here is database for tacking live user on Android Map from FCM database.

**Database structure where data is store**

```
DataSnapshot{
key=GPSLocationHistory,
value={
-KkV3nVpNuJ7uZBCob93={
  uniqueID=6430046874,
  hajjappnum=1,
  longi=74.32082333333334,
  lati=31.532981666666668,
  id=1,
  createdat=1,
  Battery=1
},
-KkUpWFDoJCom56FSpo7={
  uniqueID=6430041994,
  hajjappnum=1,
  longi=74.22081833333333,
  lati=31.321846666666666,
  id=1,
  createdat=1,
  Battery=1
},
-KkUvdMg1VX_DY4Yfhdb={
  uniqueID=6430046874,
  hajjappnum=1,
  longi=74.332855,
  lati=31.484175,
  id=1,
  createdat=1,
  Battery=1
},
-KkV23syiXLhsFqbSzDo={
  uniqueID=6430041994,
  hajjappnum=1,
  longi=74.183235,
  lati=31.38256833333333,
  id=1,
  createdat=1,
  Battery=1
},
-KkUz44sNL12yBNB6S-S={
  uniqueID=6430046874,
  hajjappnum=1,
  longi=74.32399666666667,
  lati=31.501025,
  id=1,
  createdat=1,
  Battery=1
},
-KkVJ9puLW4aBxK7LBet={
  uniqueID=6430041994,
  hajjappnum=1,
  longi=74.20848833333334,
  lati=31.316118333333332,
  id=1,
  createdat=1,
  Battery=1
},
-KkUwInngjCD3lM7NZFp={
  uniqueID=6430041994,
  hajjappnum=1,
  longi=74.22072666666666,
  lati=31.321888333333334,
  id=1,
  createdat=1,
  Battery=1
},
-KkV-pHWR_v1WuhmZNhX={
  uniqueID=6430041994,
  hajjappnum=1,
  longi=74.17445333333333,
  lati=31.38361,
  id=1,
  createdat=1,
  Battery=1
},
-KkV9FB7Dx3EvdrSZBPi={
  uniqueID=6430041994,
  hajjappnum=1,
  longi=74.20848833333334,
  lati=31.316118333333332,
  id=1,
  createdat=1,
  Battery=1
},
-KkUuV6J4dRwI5IHbiOR={
  uniqueID=6430046874,
  hajjappnum=1,
  longi=74.32752166666667,
  lati=31.49964,
  id=1,
  createdat=1,
  Battery=1
},
-KkV2p9qlZUmb1mC-2iR={
  uniqueID=6430046874,
  hajjappnum=1,
  longi=74.320855,
  lati=31.533025,
  id=1,
  createdat=1,
  Battery=1
},
-KkUkMzpK6ctgnuwDYJN={
  uniqueID=0,
  hajjappnum=1,
  longi=0,
  lati=0,
  id=1,
  createdat=190520170809,
  Battery=1
},
-KkVGw1tsrqAyF4SYJRs={
  uniqueID=6430041994,
  hajjappnum=1,
  longi=74.20848833333334,
  lati=31.316118333333332,
  id=1,
  createdat=1,
  Battery=1
},
-KkUgBL6Zs761WWJ8RC_={
  uniqueID=6430041994,
  hajjappnum=1,
  longi=74.22081833333333,
  lati=31.321846666666666,
  id=1,
  createdat=1,
  Battery=1
},
-KkUyaqSf1wvLpUlcTgi={
  uniqueID=6430041994,
  hajjappnum=1,
  longi=74.21219666666667,
  lati=31.3664,
  id=1,
  createdat=1,
  Battery=1
},
-KkUu0Ag-BMAn3HIIyXB={
  uniqueID=6430041994,
  hajjappnum=1,
  longi=74.22072666666666,
  lati=31.321888333333334,
  id=1,
  createdat=1,
  Battery=1
},
-KkVDmXZ8_abT1qVJYub={
  uniqueID=6430041994,
  hajjappnum=1,
  longi=74.20848833333334,
  lati=31.316118333333332,
  id=1,
  createdat=1,
  Battery=1
},
-KkVJpr7FU8UI8sCQfUb={
  uniqueID=6430046874,
  hajjappnum=1,
  longi=74.32071666666667,
  lati=31.533038333333334,
  id=1,
  createdat=1,
  Battery=1
},

 }
}
```

**Want to show or find 6430046874** data(Lat,Long) from DB for plot markers on Map

**6430046874 is id for Live tracking persons**

Comment: What's the problem you're having doing this? Where's your code?

Comment: Ideally, your uniqueID value should be the keys of the values